# uninstalled program in PATH

Tags: bash, gnome, path

I have uninstalled `gnome-screenshot`, but when I write `gnome` in terminal and tap `TAB`, it still suggests gnome-screenshot (and other gnome apps, but it's correct). If I want to use uninstalled gnome-screenshot, bash correctly informs that there is no such program.

```
bash: gnome-screenshot: command not found
```

`which` also can't find path to screenshot. I searched directories from PATH, but there is no file like gnome-screenshot there.

Why I can see wrong suggestion?

**EDIT:**

Thank you Kusalananda for your answer, I learned something new. I also find out that I had alias `gnome-screenshot='gnome-screenshot -i'` in my `.bashrc.`

I completely forget about it. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

The `bash` shell caches the location commands that it has found when searching the paths in `$PATH`.  This enables the shell to know that e.g. `ls` is `/bin/ls` without searching through the `$PATH` directories every time when you use `ls`.

When you uninstall a package that provides a command that has been cached in this way, the shell would not know that the cached location of the command is no longer valid until you have tried, and failed, to actually use the command.

You can empty this cache to force the shell to re-scan `$PATH` for the location of commands.  You do this with `hash -r` (see `help hash` in the `bash` shell).

So, in short, the shell still thinks that `gnome-screenshot` exists, so it completes that command's name. Run `hash -r` to make the shell forget cached locations of commands.